# Youtube Frame API: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined

Tags: youtube-iframe-api

This just started happening on my site while using the frame API, I even tried the example on the google website and it doesn't work with the same error.

Full Error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined
    at tb (www-widgetapi.js:165)
    at Gi.q.setup (www-widgetapi.js:708)
    at Gi.xi (www-widgetapi.js:692)
    at new Gi (www-widgetapi.js:723)
    at onYouTubeIframeAPIReady (<anonymous>:4:13)
    at <anonymous>:1:1
```

Here is the code I am using:

```
var tag = document.createElement('script');

tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);


var video;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    video = new YT.Player('player', {
      height: '400',
      width: '100%',
      videoId: 'dQw4w9WgXcQ',
    });
    console.log(video);
}
```

Any Ideas?